# Why wont new hard drive use battery power?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, power-supply, battery

I recently replaced the hard drive and the battery on my HP G62 laptop, Ubuntu 13.10 is installed on the drive. The machine will not boot on battery power, but works fine when plugged in.

When unplugged during use, it does not shut down or hibernate, it just cuts off. The computer recognizes the battery and charges it, but does not use it.

Is this something that can be fixed within the OS or with a new battery? The battery fits and supposedly works with the model laptop I have, but I did get it off amazon and not directly from HP.

When I was running windows 7 previous to the hard drive crash, the battery would drain and cut power, near the end without even warning it was low or going into hibernation before it cut. I thought this was due to the battery not being calibrated.

Is this because or did it cause some damage to the machine itself, that will cause issue no matter what battery/OS is used?

If so, can I continue to use it like a desktop on AC power? And would that harm the computer to have a fully charged LiIon battery in it constantly while it uses AC power?

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It _could_ theoretically also be that the new hard disk draws too much power to start up; but from the other details, this is probably not the reason. Hard disks are not power drainers.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there are several things going on:

> When unplugged during use, it does not shut down or hibernate, it just cuts off. The computer recognizes the battery and charges it, but does not use it.

This likely means you have a defective unit. I've seen laptops do this before, and it is usually fixed by trying a different battery.

> When I was running windows 7 previous to the hard drive crash, the
>   battery would drain and cut power, near the end without even warning
>   it was low or going into hibernation before it cut. I thought this was
>   due to the battery not being calibrated.

This can be caused by a battery not being calibrated as you suggested. In my experience, I have seen batteries that were calibrated but still would shut off because they were old.

> If so, can I continue to use it like a desktop on AC power? And would
>   that harm the computer to have a fully charged LiIon battery in it
>   constantly while it uses AC power?

It will not hurt your laptop to have a battery in it all the time. That said, batteries need to be exercised, and it will die much quicker if it is not regularly drained. It sounds like you have a dead battery anyway, so there won't be any additional harm.

Answer (score 1):

Your battery is faulty. Thats all there is to it.